# Is there a word for dark, cave like and claustrophobic?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for an adjective to describe a basement which is dark, cave like, and claustrophobic.

Is there a word that I can use which comes close to give the feeling of those three words?

Comment: [Tenebrous](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tenebrous), perhaps?

Comment: [Gloomy](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gloomy), perhaps but that lacks the third requirement.

Comment: [Caliginous](https://www.lexico.com/definition/caliginous), perhaps? But similar to Weather Vane's suggestion, it lacks the third property.

Answer (score 2):

I propose **sepulchral**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sepulchral) has

> **sepulchral**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **1** Relating to a tomb or interment.
> **1.1** Gloomy; dismal.

A dark and stuffy cellar might have the atmosphere of an underground tomb.

> The walls seemed to press in on us as we descended into the sepulphral basement.